# value of type '[String]' has no member 'lastObject'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have error (shoppingList.lastObject)

```
    var shoppingList = ["bananas", "milk", "vanilla ice cream"]
    var itemCount = shoppingList.count
    print("There are \(itemCount) items.")
    for item in shoppingList
    {
        print("I need to buy \(item).")
    }
    print("The most important item on my list is definitely \(shoppingList.lastObject)")
```

it says that lastObject isn't member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I will give you my code sample using some images which is directly cropped from Playground.

I will post all of the checked stages using your code only..Lastly I will post the errors also for better understanding.

**1. Your Problem(Just assuming)**
  [image: Your Problem]

**2. The Solution**
[image: Working Solution]

**3. Some Extras**
[image: Extras]

**4. Some More Extras**
[image: More Extras]

**5. Now the error which you can face in some cases**
[image: Error]

Thank You

Hope this helped.

Comment: Note that in `3` above, there is no _casting_ to an array of `String`; the type of the mutable `shoppingList` is simply explicitly included in it's declaration. This is, however, in this example, redundant, as the type of `shoppingList` is inferred to be `[String]`. Also, consider, for future reference, using code blocks rather than images of code blocks in your answers (memory footprint, mobile devices readability etc).

Answer (score 2):

It's `last` not `lastObject`:

```
var shoppingList = ["bananas", "milk", "vanilla ice cream"]
var itemCount = shoppingList.count
print("There are \(itemCount) items.")
for item in shoppingList {
    print("I need to buy \(item).")
}
print("The most important item on my list is definitely \(shoppingList.last)")
```

Note: use `.first` to get first element.

Answer (score 0):

**Array**

```
 let shoppingList = ["bananas", "milk", "vanilla ice cream"]
 print("The most important item on my list is definitely \(shoppingList.last)")
```

**NSArray**

```
 let shoppingList = ["bananas", "milk", "vanilla ice cream"] as NSArray
 print("The most important item on my list is definitely \(shoppingList.lastObject)")
```

**NSMutableArray**

```
 let shoppingList = ["bananas", "milk", "vanilla ice cream"] as NSMutableArray
 print("The most important item on my list is definitely \(shoppingList.lastObject)")
```

Comment: Using Swift Array Is preferred.

Comment: Good But this way also display same result @Zaid

Comment: I agree,but finding the correct way is better than changing the way.
I hope you get it. :)

Comment: Even if this is not a pure Swift (but rather Foundation) answer, I still think it holds enough merit for _not receiving downvotes_, at least not without leaving some feedback to the poster. Downvoters: consider giving the author feedback on how to improve this answer (the _subject_ of it does hold value in this context) rather than just drive-by-downvoting it.